# React Native Gifted Chat: what does the tile (~) mean? How do I remove it?

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

i'm testing React Native Gifted Chat on a chat application.

I'm trying to figure what this symbol ~ that appears on the messages means and how could I remove it.

[image: The symbol in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the username of sender if you want to change it

- go to node modules
- -> `react-native-gifted-chat`
- -> `lib`
- -> `bubble.js`
- search for `~` (tilde) and remove